# Arrangement of views with a scrollable layout and a filter panel

Tags: android, layout, view

I'm struggling with arranging the views of my activity.
I want to reach a simple effect:

- filter container with some text views and radios, which would be able to show/hide actions
- below: grid view with big amount of photos

Of course I want to make my view scrollable to allow user scrolling down to show all photos.
Besides I want to make filter's position fixed - placed on the very top.

This is the desired layout.

[image]

I was trying to do it in following way:

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="..."
     android:id="@+id/allViews">

    <!-- panel with some filter controls -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchOpts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/search_opts_margin"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical">

         <RadioGroup
             android:id="@+id/sortOrder"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
             android:orientation="horizontal">

             <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/orderByTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

             <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/orderByRating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
         </RadioGroup>

         <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
             android:id="@+id/tags"
             android:hint="@string/tags_label"
             android:layout_width="300dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
             android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
             android:textSize="16sp"
             android:textColor="#555"
             app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sortOrder" />

     </LinearLayout>

     <!-- panel with grid of big amount of images -->
     <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/items_grid_margin_under_search_opts"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchOpts"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

         <GridView
             android:id="@+id/PhotosGrid"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
             android:columnWidth="100dp"
             android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:numColumns="auto_fit"
             android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
             android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
             android:focusable="true"
             android:clickable="true"/>
     </ScrollView>
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Unfortunately I failed and need some help.

Comment: What was achieved & what help is wanted?

Comment: You don't need ScrollView for the Grid, it's already scrollable on its own, when there are more item that it can show in the space it has, it will scroll automatically

Comment: First of all, scroll view overlaps filter panel despite I used: app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchOpts"

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this by using a CoordinatorLayout and you would have:

1. CoordinatorLayout as a root of your layout.
2. AppBarLayout as the first child of the Coordinator Layout.
3. Add a CollapsingToolbar with a toolbar and/or a layout/custom view to represent the top part of your layout.
   **CollapsingToolbarLayout** will allow you to define scrolling behaviours to the toolbar and/or your layout that will be triggered when the bottom part of your content starts scrolling.
4. Add a Recyclerview to show the grid on the bottom part of your mock up and specify the layout behaviour so that it can properly scroll the stuff inside the app bar layout.

Here is an example of how your layout would look like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <CustomViewHeader
                android:id="@+id/custom_view_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You could learn more about it here: https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/