# RecyclerView in Scrollview (nested?), how to bind items dynamically?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I am creating a simple view where on the top I have some elements and below a **recyclerView**. When I scroll it down, would like to scroll the whole screen, not the only recycler.

I have achieved it with **NestedScrollView**, however, now the problem appears. Items in the list will be pretty heavy and in this configuration, all the items are bind at the same time(call of **onBindViewHolder**).

any ideas how to make them recycle and solve this problem?

Here is my xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.gkuziel.testkotlin.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_available_stores_default" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test text" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_test"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Update:**

The found a sweet solution: you add a complex header as ItemDecoration, its great cause your adapter can stay untouched, you just add sth like this:
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
the only drawback of this solution is i couldn't make this header clickable (in my case it contains another recyclerView), however I know some people achieved it as well.

For this moment I decided implement heterogeneous recyclerview, with 1 instance of header type and the rest of simple row types.

What is important, the header type is fully binded once in HeaderViewHolder constructor and onBindViewHolder looks like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder is HeaderViewHolder) {
        //do nothing
        Log.d("ProductAdapter", "Binding: Header")

    } else if (holder is ItemViewHolder) {
        Log.d("ProductAdapter", "Binding: " + position.toString())
        val searchItem = items!![position - 1]

        //here the proper binding is going on
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a header view in your Recycler view.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910751/arrangement-of-views-with-a-scrollable-layout-and-a-filter-panel/47912554#47912554

Comment: Add a size as a place holder for the images in the items of the recyclerview, so it doenst occupy a 1px making it inflate all in the screen

Comment: mudit_sen - I think its not possible as there will be small recyclerView as well above the main recyclerView..

Comment: realdm - i think its different case, but will have a look later
Marcos Vasconcelos - it has already fixed size, problem is somewhere else

Comment: @goyo you can add different type of views in a single Recyclerview. In onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) in this method the view type is what you have to use to get a different type of view which to be inflated in your RV, and also look for getItemViewType to return viewtype based on position.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the recyclerview layout manager's method canScrollVertical to false and it won't respond to any touch inner scroll events.

override below method and return false.

```
boolean canScrollVertically()
```

here it is how to set.

```
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // ...
         // Lookup the recyclerview in activity layout
         RecyclerView listTest = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_test);

         // Attach the adapter to the recyclerview to populate items
         listTest.setAdapter(adapter);
         // Set layout manager to position the items
         listTest.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this){
         @Override
         public boolean canScrollVertically(){
         return false;
       }        
     });
         // That's all!
     }
```